# Embedding a UIScrollView with a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So Path uses this type of page where there is a view above their customized looking table that is a background photo, which contains some user info among other things. I'm trying to recreate something very similar to this.

So lets say that I hypothetically wanted to make a view that shows exactly the way the Path app does, but instead of that weird customized version of a table view that they have, there is an actual table. How would I do something like this? The reason why I would need there to be another `UIScrollView` embedded into the view is because the entire thing needs the capability to scroll. I'm trying to be as detailed as possible, but its a little difficult to explain.

What I'm imagining is going to happen if I just tried it right now, is that I'd embed a `UIView` above a `UITableView` within a `UIScrollView` that's the size of the frame, and when I'd go to scroll, the user would only scroll the `UITableView`, and not the entire thing at once. Hopefully that helps convey my doubts.

Another possibility is that I'm totally over thinking this, and I can simply just subclass a view in the header of a `UITableView` and it would stretch the width and height that I'd like. Hopefully this is the way as this would be easy!

Anyways, can anybody weigh in on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path just uses a normal `UITableView` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

The custom view at the top is the header of the first section of the table.

They also access the UIScrollViewDelegate method of the UITableView to change the look of the view (I think the image is moved) when the scroll view scrolls.

If you'd like a tableview that only scrolls within a part of the view and other stuff above it then you need to use a `UIViewController`. Then you can make it conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` and add a `UITableView` and make the view controller the datasource and delegate.

Then you can also add a UIScrollView to it as well.

Comment: That sounds like a total pain in the ass. I think the first way you mentioned is the actual way that I want to do it. Unless I'm misinterpreting what you're saying, this is going to take some time...

Comment: I have used the UIViewController with a UITableView method hundreds of times for UI layout stuff. It's really useful any time you want a table view but not to cover the entire screen. It really depends on how you want the custom view bit (that isn't the table) to move when you scroll the table.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not worried about that. I'm more so not looking forward to having to mess around with the UIScrollViewDelegate and make it cooperate with my `UITableView` `UIView` combo. :(

Comment: You won't have to. Create your custom view in... `- (UIView)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;` return your custom view and done.

Comment: Phew! I just misinterpreted what you were saying then. +1 for you sir!